# Finding what the clientHeight will be after layout

Tags: javascript, word-wrap

I have a div with a series of spans under it (this.content). The div had "word-wrap: break-word", "min-width: 400px" and "white-space: normal" and "overflow-x: auto:".

I need to calculate the number of lines the text will wrap to. I was hoping to go this route:

```
            var hiddenParent = document.createElement("div");
            hiddenParent.style.width = width + "px";
            hiddenParent.style.height = "20000px";
            hiddenParent.style.display = "block";
            hiddenParent.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
            hiddenParent.style.whiteSpace = "normal";
            hiddenParent.style.overflowX = "auto";
            hiddenParent.style.maxWidth = hiddenParent.style.width;
            var newElement = TreeDataItem.HtmlElementSource.createElement("div");
            newElement.style.maxWidth = hiddenParent.style.maxWidth;
            hiddenParent.appendChild(newElement);
            newElement.innerHTML = this.content;
            rows newElement.style.clientHeight/charHeight;
```

But the clientHeight doesn't get calculated. I don't want it rendered so I was putting it under a hiddentElement.

I'm missing something obvious or I can't do this. Help!

Comment: Usually if you give us a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example, you can attract more help.

Comment: you can't get dimensions of a hidden element. It is taking up no space.

Comment: Rats! I was hoping I could do it hidden. I don't want a flicker.